# jquery token input dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plugins, jquery-tokeninput

I dont get any errors with this one but as I re-checked the plugin it should only toggle "admin admin" in the dropdown list. I am using the latest version of jquery. So far, I have read on this **[site](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues)** that it doesn't support the latest version of jquery.

JSON output works fine. I dunno how to solve this.

```
//Code Initialisation:

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#input").tokenInput("JSONurlhere");
    });
</script>
```

[image: jquery token search]

Comment: Please add the code you are using to initialise this plugin.

Comment: If you check the network traffic in firebug (or equivalent) what is the response coming back? Is your server side code actually filtering the data?

Comment: Yep. everything works fine. I'm thinking this is a plugin issue. Probably because of the jquery version I used...

Comment: It does sound that that is the case. It may be worth contacting the plugin author.

Answer (score 0):

When using an external page to access your data, you also need to implement the search logic yourself. This is to allow the add-on too search databases and such as well. Whatever you echo is what is displayed in the dropdown, so should just be the relevant results.

With the above set up, your search parameter (In the example 'admin') will be available in the GET variable `q` on your server side script.